# dyld symbol not found? _UIAccessibilityNotificationVoiceOverIdentifier

Tags: ios, dyld

My App compile and work on an iPhone with iOS9 but failed with this issue on an iPhone with iOS8.4?

> dyld: Symbol not found:
>   _UIAccessibilityNotificationVoiceOverIdentifier   Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EEFA3096-700D-4415-9875-861A5992544F/XXX.app/Demo
>   Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit  in
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EEFA3096-700D-4415-9875-861A5992544F/XXX.app/Demo

I can't find to which library this `_UIAccessibilityNotificationVoiceOverIdentifier` is related?

Comment: have u checked with deployment target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to cocoapods 0.39 and specifying `use_frameworks!` have fix my issue